# ContentAlignment Error on ListBoxItem. Style.Setter is not applied

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I get the following databinding error:

`System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'ListBoxItem' (Name=''); target property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')`

even if my ListBox.ItemContainerStyle does specify a different value.

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
      <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
      <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource EmptyFocusVisualStyle}" />
      <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
               <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" />
            </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

But the Item does not show a DataBinding Error if i check it with Snoop. Althought Snoop shows a valid DataBinding even if i set the value to a constant not a binding?!
the other setters in the style work as expected.

Setting the Style in a higher level does not resolve the error. 
Can anybody help me?

EDIT: I did ofc read through a lot of similar qustions here, but the answers there did not solve my Problem.

EDIT 2:
I know that the Error points to the Default template of the ListBoxItem which contains the Binding. And i know that this is a common issue, but in most threads i read the solotion is to set a style in the App.xaml / Ressources / ItemContainerStyle. My problem is that all the approaches did not solve my issue.

Don't get my wrong i just wan't to make it clear. Suppressing or ignoring this errors is not an option. Bindings will get unmaintainable in a huge application.

EDIT 3:
After further investigation i found out this only happens if i add items to the ListBox in the constructor of the StartUpUri Window (after InitializeComponent), If i add items after this (events, other forms, or dispatched) there is no DataBinding issue anymore.

Comment: The problem is elsewhere, where is the `Binding` with `RelativeSource` mentioned by Output window ?

Comment: The problem is in the default template of ListBoxItem which contains a TemplateBinding. Should clarify that ofc, will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error and occurs in the default `ControlTemplate` of the `ListBoxItem` and `MenuItem` classes and is nothing to do with your code. It tries to find the nearest `ItemsControl` ancestor and bind to the `VerticalContentAlignment` and `HorizontalContentAlignment` properties, but as you don't have any in your code, you get this warning.

The exceptions are handled internally, so you can simply ignore these warnings. There are a number of so called fixes that work to varying degrees. One such example is just to set these properties in a `Style`, but this fix didn't help when I had this problem (I can see that you tried this too):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
</Style>
```

Either way, they're just warnings and have no negative effect on the application, so you can just ignore them (as annoying as they are).  If you put that error message into a search engine (you'll have to remove the punctuation), then you'll find a great many more posts on this exact subject.

Comment: i should have mentioned that i know the default template implementation. But the problem is that even if i declare a style in my App.xaml i still get the binding error above while for most ppl this seems to solve it. And even more curious that snoop shows a valid databinding for the VerticalContentAlignment in my visual tree. And the ListBoxItem is under a ListBox in the visual Tree which should let the TemplateBinding find the ItemsControl it is searching for.

Comment: Yeah, that would have saved me some time. Either way, one of my applications has the same problem in one particular view. At first, I found it annoying too and tried a few methods to remove the warnings. They didn't work for me either, but after learning the reason for these warnings and that they had no negative effect on the application, I just decided to ignore them. I only see them when working on that view and seeing as it has been fully implemented already, I don't need to ever work on it... out of sight, out of mind.